# Animation two elements when hover the div box?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I want to make this close button that when i hover through it does this animation. One line has to go to one side and viceversa, but I'm stuck with this and i don't know if there is a solution. Its like the have to do a 360deg travel when the mouse enters in the parent (close) aera, or something like that, but the main purpose is that both of them to work at the same tame, the thing that i cant achieve. ´
Thank you in advance <3

```css
#close {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#close .bar5,
#close .bar6,
#close .bar7 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0s;
}

.bar5:hover {
  animation: rota2 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bar7:hover {
  animation: rota1 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bar5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.bar6 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bar7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}

@keyframes rota1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)translate(-6px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg)translate(-6px, -8px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(-320deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  }
}

@keyframes rota2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(-6px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(-6px, 6px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(320deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(320deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="close">
  <div class="bar5"></div>
  <div class="bar6"></div>
  <div class="bar7"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `>`to select  immediate child element and assign effect to it.

I remove your padding style since it will make the `hover` effect doesn't work as expected.

```css
#close {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#close .bar5,
#close .bar6,
#close .bar7 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0s;
}
#close:hover > .bar5{
animation: rota1 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
#close:hover > .bar7{
animation: rota2 1.2s ease-in-out;
}


.bar5 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.bar6 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.bar7 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}

@keyframes rota1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)translate(-6px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg)translate(-6px, -8px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(-320deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
    }
}

@keyframes rota2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(-6px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(-6px, 6px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(320deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(320deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="close">
                    <div class="bar5"></div>
                    <div class="bar6"></div>
                    <div class="bar7"></div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Mate, thank you so much, this is the answer i needed. I don't really know so much about parents and children, so thxxx <33

Comment: @Izar， no problem, see [what should I do when people solve my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)